# Distinguish between one-, two- and three-word commands

Tags: java, split, command, java-stream

Right now, I am using this method to check if the user just typed in a command with wrong arguments:

```
    private boolean relatedCommand(String input) {
        // make sure the split afterwards has at least size one
        if (input.matches(" .*")) {
            return false;
        }
        final String command = input.split(" ".toString())[0];
        return COMMAND_PACKAGE
                .keySet()
                .stream()
                .map(Pattern::toString)
                .anyMatch(patternText -> patternText.startsWith(command + " ");
    }
```

(COMMAND_PACKAGE contains all registered commands)

Now, this works perfectly fine for one-word commands. E. g. `get <argument1> <argument2>`, `remove <argument1>`.

However, I am currently working on a project that has both one-word and two-word commands.
Here is a range of commands that doesn't really work with this method:
`add track <argument1>`, `add switch <argument1>`, `step <argument>`. In this case, for the command `add track <argument1>`, "track" is seen as an argument but it really belongs to the command itself.

If the use just types in "add" the error message is "invalid arguments". Instead, the error message should be more precise and tell him that this command doesn't exist (as there is only "add track" or "add switch").

Does anyone have any idea how to distinguish between one-word and two-word commands? The user can also use the command `delete rolling stock <argument>` which consists of a three-word command.

All in all, it is therefore necessary to differentiate between commands of one, two and three words.

Comment: well, kind of have only one word commands - the `"add"` command would then check if the first argument is a `"track"`  or a `"switch"` and continue with the corresponding parsing; otherwise it should output an error message | you could also have a list (map) of commands and use `startsWith()` to find if input is valid (Obs: `" ".toString()` ??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, the simplest and the most efficient method of solving this is to create the list of commands that have two or three words and then simply perform matching in a separate method, so that if You hit a keyword that is part of longer command you check for the next word to see if it's the part of the command You are expecting.

Depending on the exact specification of the commands and so on, You could perhaps use the `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>` to represent the commands. This way You could simply do something like storing the prefix as key and then suffixes as values.

Answer (score 0):

The method `String.split("\s+")` splits your input at whitespaces into an array. You can query the length of that arrays, then you know how many words your input contained.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a command");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String command=in.nextLine();
        String[] parts=command.split("\\s+");
        System.out.println("parts="+Arrays.toString(parts));
        if (parts.length==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Zero parts");
        }
        else if (parts.length==1)
        {
            System.out.println("One part");
        }
        else if (parts.length==2)
        {
            System.out.println("Two parts");
        }
        else if (parts.length==3)
        {
            System.out.println("Three parts");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("More than three parts");
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Enter a command
a b c
parts=[a, b, c]
Three parts
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: This is a good solution only if You assume that command can have only one argument :) Otherwise, its impossible to distinguish the `mv <from> <to>` from `add switch <to>` just by taking a look at length.

Comment: What about commands that have multiple arguments. E. g. `add track <argument1> <argument2> <argument3> <argument4>`. How do I know where the command ends and the arguments start?

Comment: If the command itself can contain different count of words, then you need to check the command itself as well in the if-expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using a `LinkedHashMap` and then putting the commands in order of most complex (w/ spaces) first.  That way they will be matched first.

A `LinkedHashMap` preserves the order in which you add keys.